# Fill new columns based on key words of an existing column

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below and I would like to create new columns based on key words in each row of the `INFO` column.

```
ID<-c(1,2,3,4)
INFO<-c("You used works apps for 4 minutes today.","You checked your phone 10 times today.",
        "Your commute time to work today was 4 minutes.","You (or at least your phone) were at your work place for 15 minutes today"
        )
DATASET<-data.frame(ID,INFO)
```

More specifically I have to check each row of the `INFO` for the words `apps,phone,commute,or`. Then one new column for each one will be created and it will have either `NA` or the number that exists in this row so my new dataset will be like:

```
DATASET2
  ID                                                                      INFO apps phone commute or
1  1                                  You used works apps for 4 minutes today.    4    NA      NA    NA
2  2                                    You checked your phone 10 times today.   NA    10      NA    NA
3  3                            Your commute time to work today was 4 minutes.   NA    NA       4    NA
4  4 You (or at least your phone) were at your work place for 15 minutes today   NA    NA      NA    15
```

Comment: No those phrases are standard except of the number. And the key words are unique

Comment: In the 4th row, there is phone and place

Comment: thanks I replaced with or

Comment: I edited it. You search for these 4 unique keywords and if you find one you put the number in the relative column of thiskey word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution involving `purrr`, `stringr` and `dplyr` could be:

```
bind_cols(DATASET, 
          map_dfc(.x = c("apps", "phone", "commute", "place"),
                  ~ DATASET %>%
                   mutate(!!.x := ifelse(str_detect(INFO, .x), 
                                         str_extract_all(INFO, "\\d+"), 
                                         NA_character_)) %>%
                   select(.x)))

  ID                                                                      INFO apps phone commute place
1  1                                  You used works apps for 4 minutes today.    4  <NA>    <NA>  <NA>
2  2                                    You checked your phone 10 times today. <NA>    10    <NA>  <NA>
3  3                            Your commute time to work today was 4 minutes. <NA>  <NA>       4  <NA>
4  4 You (or at least your phone) were at your work place for 15 minutes today <NA>    15    <NA>    15
```

If there could be more than one number per row:

```
bind_cols(DATASET, 
          map_dfc(.x = c("apps", "phone", "commute", "place"),
                  ~ DATASET %>%
                   mutate(!!.x := map_chr(ifelse(str_detect(INFO, .x), 
                                                 str_extract_all(INFO, "\\d+"), 
                                                 NA_character_), 
                                          toString)) %>%
                   select(.x)))
```

Comment: Can this be applied in a dataset with more than 4 rows? Cause when I use it in a bigger I get: Error: Column `apps` must be length 56 (the number of rows) or one, not 4

Comment: Yes, it should work with any number of rows and also key words. Perhaps add the first 10 rows of your actual data using `dput()`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option:

```
library(tidyverse)

DATASET %>%
  mutate(INFO = as.character(INFO),
         name =  str_extract_all(INFO, "apps|phone|commute|place"),
         number = parse_number(INFO)) %>%
  unnest_longer(col = name) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "name", values_from = "number")
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>      ID INFO                                            apps phone commute place
#>   <dbl> <chr>                                          <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1 You used works apps for 4 minutes today.           4    NA      NA    NA
#> 2     2 You checked your phone 10 times today.            NA    10      NA    NA
#> 3     3 Your commute time to work today was 4 minutes.    NA    NA       4    NA
#> 4     4 You (or at least your phone) were at your wor…    NA    15      NA    15
```

Answer (score 1):

here is an option with `base R`

```
v1 <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D+",  "", DATASET$INFO))
words <-  c("apps", "phone", "commute", "place")
cbind(DATASET, sapply(words, function(x) {
     i1 <- grepl(x, DATASET$INFO)
     NA^(!(i1 & !duplicated(i1)))}) * v1)
#ID                                                                      INFO apps phone commute place
#1  1                                  You used works apps for 4 minutes today.    4    NA      NA    NA
#2  2                                    You checked your phone 10 times today.   NA    10      NA    NA
#3  3                            Your commute time to work today was 4 minutes.   NA    NA       4    NA
#4  4 You (or at least your phone) were at your work place for 15 minutes today   NA    NA      NA    15
```